# Como saber cual es el primer número de un input?

Tags: javascript, input

Necesito saber como hacer para sacar el primer numero de un input.

por ejemplo alguien ingresa:

42862 => 4

992 => 9

12345 => 1

pero con JavaScript, que debo hacer??

Comment: Por favor, añade el código (avance) que tienes hasta ahorita para que puedas recibir ayuda, de lo contrario, tu pregunta terminará cerrada por no cumplir los lineamientos del sitio.

Comment: no tengo código, solo es para saber como hacerle @Rodrigo

Comment: Como dice @Rodrigo, tienes que agregar un ejemplo de lo que intentaste hasta el momento, en este sitio estamos para ayudarte en donde te trabaste, no para programar por ti. Por favor lee [ask] para seguir los lineamientos. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

puedes hacerlos accediendo al primer elemento

ejemplo:

```js
function extraer(){
  // obtenemos el valor del input
  let v=document.querySelector("input").value;
  // validamos
  // nota isNAN retorna false si se le pasa un numero
  // por ello lo negamos 
  if(!isNaN(v)){
     // accedemos al primer indice v[0]
     alert(`el primer numero es ${v[0]}`);
  }else{
     alert(`no es un numero valido!`);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text">

<button onclick="extraer()">extraer</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta que te dio @Byro, está complementada, pero si tu `<input>`, NO es de tipo **number**, el código podría causarte inconvenientes.

Si admites todo tipo de caracteres alfanuméricos en tu `<input>`, podrías usar una expresión regular ó separar el valor e ir recorriéndolo con un ciclo `for` para encontrar el primer número.

---

Explicando más a fondo, los `<input>`s tienen una propiedad que se llama `value`, esta propiedad contiene lo que está escrito en el elemento.

Ahora bien, el valor de esta propiedad será de tipo `string`, en realidad, para sacar la primera letra de un string, existen varias formas. La más corta, es usar los corchetes y referirnos al índice 0 (donde comienza cada string o array) para obtener la primera letra.

---

```js
const input = document.querySelector("#prueba");
const btn = document.querySelector("#enviar");

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Forma uno
  {
    const val = input.value;
    const primerNumero = (val.match(/[0-9]/) || [])[0];
    if (primerNumero) console.log(primerNumero);
  }  
  // Forma dos
  {
    const val = input.value;
    for(let i = 0; i < val.split("").length; i++) {
      const el = val.split("")[i];
      if (!isNaN(el)) {
        console.log(el);
        return;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="prueba">
<button id="enviar">Primer número</button>
```

---

Entrando en detalles, la siguiente expresión:

```js
(val.match(/[0-9]/) || [])
```

Es para evitar errores, pues el prototipo `match`, dará `null` si no encuentra coincidencias con el patrón indicado, al intentar acceder al índice 0 de `null`, el intérprete tirará un error porque `null` NO es iterable ni tiene valores

Con la expresión dada al intérprete, le estamos dando a entender que, si un valor es evaluado como falso (ya sea `undefined`, `null`, `false` etc), que elija el otro valor. Por lo que, el valor dentro de los paréntesis SIEMPRE será un array, así evitamos problemas con el intérprete, luego intentamos acceder al índice 0, si este no existe, simplemente dará `undefined`

La otra forma es una tanto más extensa, pero fácil de entender. Se trata de separar el string por medio de su prototipo `split`, como le damos un string vacío, nos lo separará letra por letra y con el bucle iremos recorriendo cada carácter del string, iremos comprobando con cada uno si es un número.

Ten en cuenta que, con la función `parseInt`, podemos convertir strings a números. Además, los strings que no sean convertibles o que no sean numéricos darán `NaN`. La función `isNaN`, nos ahorra el trabajo de `parseInt`

```js
console.log(
  isNaN("abcd24..."), // true, aunque incluye números, no es completamente numérico
  isNaN("25") // false
);
```

Iremos teniendo un condicional para detectar si un carácter es o no numérico, si lo es, usaremos `return`, para parar la ejecución del bucle.

---

Puedes referenciarte de los siguientes enlaces.

- [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN)
- [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)
- [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN)

Answer (score 0):

Supongamos que tienes lo siguiente:

```
<input type="text" id="texto-prueba" />
<input type="submit" value="probar" id="submit-button" />
```

y ahora capturas con jQuery el valor de la siguiente forma:

```
$('#submit-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var texto = $('#texto-prueba').val();
  console.log(texto[0]);
})
```